# Using untyped javascript modules with Typescript: Property does not exist on type 'unknown'

Tags: javascript, typescript, svelte-3

I'm working on a new Svelte project using Typescript. I'm also using the svelte-mui component module which was not written in Typescript and does not have a types file. Whenever I try to use a component, VSCode highlights the component with annoying red squiggles because Typescript doesn't know about the svelte properties that are a part of the object. The project builds and runs fine, but I would like to figure out how to tell Typescript what type they are. I know all the components extend `SvelteComponent` but I don't know how to tell Typescript that.

```
<script>
import Button from 'svelte-mui';
</script>

<Button on:click={() => {console.log('Clicked')}}>My Button</Button>
```

The last line will be highlighted as an error in the editor.

How do I tell Typescript that Button extends SvelteComponent?

Edit: @tmdesigned

I followed the instructions in the link provided by tmdesigned below, but no dice. I'm new to Typescript so maybe I'm still doing something wrong. I ended up with a file located at

`types\svelte-mui\index.d.ts`

that contains

```
declare module 'svelte-mui' {
    import { SvelteComponent } from "svelte/internal";

    class Button extends SvelteComponent{}

    export { Button }
}
```

but the error still persists.

Comment: I should probably add that I can import SvelteComponent with

```import { SvelteComponent } from 'svelte/internal';```

Comment: https://www.detroitlabs.com/blog/2018/02/28/adding-custom-type-definitions-to-a-third-party-library/

Comment: @tmdesigned Thanks for the link, but the error still persists. See the edit above.

Answer (score 1):

I hit similar errors using [Svelte Material UI](https://sveltematerialui.com/), but the solution should translate to `svelte-mui`.

First, configure `typeRoots` in `tsconfig.json` so that the compiler finds your declaration file in the `types` directory:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
     ...
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types",
      "./types"
    ]
  }
}
```

Make sure not to add "types" to the `exclude` list as suggested by the linked page that you mentioned. I think that would prevent the compiler from using your declaration file.

Then, update `types/svelte-mui/index.d.ts` to:

```
declare module 'svelte-mui' {
  import type { SvelteComponent } from "svelte";

  class Button extends SvelteComponent { }
  export default Button;
}
```

Restart VSCode or run the "Svelte: Restart Language Server" command to ensure that it uses the new configuration. Your `Button` component should no longer show an error.